# Multinomial confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to help out a quality auditing department and figure out sample sizes and confidence intervals and such. The sample size and confidence level (95%) is pretty well documented on the web and I am muddling through it. I even figured out how to do the exact confidence level of a [binomial sample](http://statpages.org/confint.html) which I would use for a pass/fail condition but I wanted to figure out how to do a multinomial of that same sample so that I could generate some type of information about a situation with three possibilities: pass / fail(critical) / fail(non-critical).

Can someone point me in the right direction here? Ultimately I am going to want to program this into an application so a formula would get me going, a link to a way to program it would be a home run.

Comment: You could simply look at the three proportions and endow each of them with a binomial confidence interval.

Comment: @MichaelM do you mean looking at each proportion as its own result, and calculate pass (vs non-pass), fail-critical (vs non-fail-critical) and fail-noncritical (vs non-fail-noncritical) using the whole survey as population each time? I'm looking at doing something similar for say, an election poll with eight parties, and I want a confidence interval for each.

Comment: Basically yes. Although the whole survey seems to be the sample, not the population. The idea is similar to representing a categorical variable by several dummies and then infer about the true proportions of '1' for each dummy.