# Using binomial confidence intervals for multinomial confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution

Below is sample code showing the widths of binomial confidence intervals (using a [simple normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval)) and multinomial "simultaneous confidence intervals" (from [MultinomialCI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MultinomialCI/index.html)).  I picked counts high enough that I hope the simple normal approximation for a 95% confidence interval is reasonable. The multinomial widths are ~0.007, and the binomial widths ~0.006 (narrower ?!  I would expect them wider).

Can I trust the binomial confidence intervals?  Looks like they are more conservative because they don't take advantage of the extra information that the distribution adds to 1.

Some [previous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74767/multinomial-confidence-interval) [questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175756/multinomial-proportion-confidence-interval) say I can just use the binomial confidence intervals.

```
library(MultinomialCI)
library(tidyverse)

count_vec = c(23000, 12000, 44000)
m = multinomialCI(count_vec, 0.05)
print(paste("First class: [", m[1,1], m[1,2], "]"));
# [1] "First class: [ 0.28746835443038 0.294817894364861 ]"
print(paste("First width: ", m[1,2] - m[1,1]));
# [1] "First width:  0.0073495399344809"
print(paste("Second class: [", m[2,1], m[2,2], "]"));
# [1] "Second class: [ 0.148227848101266 0.155577388035747 ]"
print(paste("Second width: ", m[2,2] - m[2,1]));
# [1] "Second width:  0.00734953993448095"
print(paste("Third class: [", m[3,1], m[3,2], "]"));
# [1] "Third class: [ 0.553291139240506 0.560640679174987 ]"
print(paste("Third width: ", m[3,2] - m[3,1]));
# [1] "Third width:  0.00734953993448095"

the_counts = data.frame(name=c('a', 'b', 'c'), count=count_vec)
the_counts = the_counts %>% mutate(
  frac = count / sum(count),
  c95 = 1.96 * sqrt(frac * (1-frac) / sum(count)),
  ul = frac + c95,
  ll = frac - c95)

  name count      frac         c95        ul        ll
1    a 23000 0.2911392 0.003167914 0.2943072 0.2879713
2    b 12000 0.1518987 0.002502900 0.1544016 0.1493958
3    c 44000 0.5569620 0.003463983 0.5604260 0.5534980
```

**EDIT**: Or should `frac * (1-frac) / count` be `frac * (1-frac) / sum(count)`?  That is, should the denominator be all the observations in all the groups?  I think no?

**EDIT 2**: [Here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/15/confidence-intervals-multinomial-proportions.html) is a blog post with six methods to compute multinomial confidence intervals.  What I don't need is more suggestions of methods.  What I do need is to know whether to trust one or both of the ones I already mentioned.  Thanks.

**EDIT 3**: [Another related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20555/simultaneous-confidence-intervals-for-multinomial-parameters-for-small-samples#20589).

**EDIT 4**: Looking at the two-class results goes the other way: the multinomial intervals are MUCH smaller (0.0000035) than the binomial intervals (~0.005) in this example.  This doesn't make sense.  They should be the same for two classes.

```
count_vec = c(23000, 12000)
m = multinomialCI(count_vec, 0.05)
print(paste("First class: [", m[1,1], m[1,2], "]"));
print(paste("First width: ", m[1,2] - m[1,1]));
print(paste("Second class: [", m[2,1], m[2,2], "]"));
print(paste("Second width: ", m[2,2] - m[2,1]));
# [1] "First class: [ 0.657142857142857 0.657146383075623 ]"
# [1] "First width:  3.5259327655357e-06"
# [1] "Second class: [ 0.342857142857143 0.342860668789908 ]"
# [1] "Second width:  3.52593276548019e-06"

the_counts = data.frame(name=c('a', 'b'), count=count_vec)
the_counts = the_counts %>% mutate(
  frac = count / sum(count),
  c95 = 1.96 * sqrt(frac * (1-frac) / sum(count)),
  ul = frac + c95,
  ll = frac - c95)

> the_counts
name count      frac         c95        ul        ll
1    a 23000 0.6571429 0.004972886 0.6621157 0.6521700
2    b 12000 0.3428571 0.004972886 0.3478300 0.3378843
```

**EDIT 5**: Fix the denominator of the binomial to be `sum(counts)`.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret them.  The Normal approximation is excellent with these counts, but the point of using a multinomial model is that the individual estimates are (negatively) correlated.  This suggests you ought to be interested in a simultaneous confidence *region.* Have you considered using a multivariate Normal approximation that accounts for the correlation? It ought to work extremely well--but does not appear even to be mentioned in that blog post.

Comment: I appreciate your comment! However, as I said in the post, I'm not looking for more options yet. The world is a big place. I'm first looking to learn more about the options I have at hand. First, if I can trust one or both of them. Second, if one or the other might under- or over-estimate.